# Jquery UI Autocomplete with JSON not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hey guys I am trying to figure out why the `autocomplete()` method is not doing a `GET` when I add a variable to the end of the source. For example:

```
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var search_input;

        $('#search').keyup(function(){
            search_input = ($(this).val());
            console.log(search_input);
        });
        $('#search').autocomplete({
          source: "http://192.168.33.10/app_dev.php/search/query/" + search_input,
          minLength: 2
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="search">Search</label>
        <input type="text" id="search" />
    </div>
```

Yet if I remove `+ search_input` from the source it will do a `GET`, like so..

```
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var search_input;

        $('#search').keyup(function(){
            search_input = ($(this).val());
            console.log(search_input);
        });
        $('#search').autocomplete({
          source: "http://192.168.33.10/app_dev.php/search/query/",
          minLength: 2
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="search">Search</label>
        <input type="text" id="search" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the `autocomplete` function just needs to provide the source parameter with a callback function. `source: function( request, response ) {}`

You can follow the example for [Multiple remote suggestions on jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote)

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(function() {
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#search" )
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
          $.getJSON( "http://192.168.33.10/app_dev.php/search/query/" + extractLast( request.term ), {
            term: extractLast( request.term )
          }, response );
        },
        search: function() {
          // custom minLength
          var term = extractLast( this.value );
          if ( term.length < 2 ) {
            return false;
          }
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          return false;
        }
      });
  });
        </script>
```

The JSON returned by the server in this example would be structured like this:

```
[{"id":"1544","label":"Suggestion 1","value":"Suggestion 1"},
{"id":"3321","label":"Suggestion 2","value":"Suggestion 2"}]
```

Comment: I have an additional question. I would like to categorize the search results with a label like here http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories. I am confused how I can integrate that code into the working one you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're changing `search_input`, the widget is only getting the URL with the initial value of `search_input` (which is probably empty).

Something like this is what you need:

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.get("http://192.168.33.10/app_dev.php/search/query/" + request.term, response)
    },
    minLength: 2
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I am getting the correct JSON response in the drop down but the formatting is weird. It is actually pulling every single character from the JSON though including the [ { : " and the key names one character at a time. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Can you provide a sample response from your service? You could also try using `getJSON` instead